# Perform a piece of code based on input

Tags: c, cs50

I got the following code (see below). Works fine, only I want to make one thing happen. I now ask for user input. If the input is 0 or below zero, I want to make sure the rest of the code does not run.

Any suggestion on how to do this?

```
#include <cs50.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <stdio.h>


int
main(void)
{
float change = 0;
int quarter = 25, dime = 10, nickel = 5, penny = 1;
int quarterc = 0, dimec = 0, nickelc = 0, pennyc = 0; 


printf("For what amount should I perform the calculation\n");
change = GetFloat();
if (change == 0)
{
printf("No change!");
// And code should be terminated!
} else if (change < 0)

{
printf("This is a negative number");
// And code should be terminated!    
}

else {
printf("You entered this amount: %.1f\n", change);
}

change = change * 100;

        while (change >= quarter)
        {
            change = change - quarter;
            quarterc++;
        }

        while (change >= dime)
        {
            change = change - dime;
            dimec++;
        }

        while (change >= nickel)
        {
            change = change - nickel;
            nickelc++;
        }


        while (change >= penny)
        {
            change = change - penny;
            pennyc++;
        }

        // print number of minimum quarters, dimes, nickels, and pennies needed
        printf( "You owe the following number of coins as change:\n");
        printf( "quarters = %d\n" , quarterc);
        printf( "dimes    = %d\n" , dimec);
        printf( "nickels  = %d\n" , nickelc);
        printf( "pennies  = %d\n" , pennyc);

        // print total minimum number of coins needed for change
        printf("The total number of coins needed for change: %d\n", quarterc + dimec + nickelc + pennyc);
        }
```

Comment: learn if, - this is really not a question.

Comment: Look at flow control statements, like `return`. And maybe break the method into a few functions that make that easier.

Answer (score 3):

Change

```
// And code should be terminated!
```

to

```
return 0;
```

Comment: Or maybe `return 1`, if you want to indicate errors (such as entering negative numbers).

Comment: @Thilo It depends on OS that 1 is fail or success, C provides macros `EXIT_SUCCESS` and `EXIT_FAILURE`

Comment: @GrijeshChauhan - But is it success of failure? Need context